# How to instrument a standard library type

Tags: c++, instrumentation

For some class `A`, I need to know whether the code I'm writing triggers calls to the constructor, copy or move constructor (there might be more things I want to watch but these would suffice).

Now when I'm the author of `A` I typically use code as :

```
class A {
public:
    A()         { cout << "default constructor called\n"; }
    A(A const&) { cout << "copy    constructor called\n"; }
    A(A&&)      { cout << "move constructor called\n";    }
};
```

But when I have to do the same thing for standard library types, `std::string` for example, I always find myself sweating over the debugger to see what calls I'll step through. Is there a better way ? Please don't suggest me to modify the STL, that's an obvious solution that wouldn't scale (I won't modify all standard types) plus I don't think I'll always have access to those files (eg in VS these are read only files)

Comment: Most debuggers will allow you to execute script code at a breakpoint. For example, in `gdb` you can do stuff like this: http://kfunk.org/2014/08/29/scripting-gdb-to-execute-commands-at-particular-breakpoints/ What debugger are you using?

Comment: I know VS lets you print values of variables at breakpoints, it probably lets you do more than that (but it's been years since I've used VS). I suggest you change the title of your post and add tags for Visual Studio, that might attract more answers.

Comment: What is the purpose? Such instrumentation won't easily tell you from where the constructors are being called anyway. You need a debugger for that anyway. Or a profiler, which might actually be a nice trick for this. Profiling in call tracing mode will list all places from which a function (each function; you just pick the constructor you are interested in) was called.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Visual Studio. How about using `penter`

Check these:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c63a9b7h.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xy06s51.aspx